# ng-table filter after hitting submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ngtable

I'm using ng-table in AngularJS with a Ruby on Rails backend. I'm using ng-table to display 10 rows at a time and I'm doing the search/sort and pagination on the server side.

The problem I'm having is the filter is sending a request to the server after every keystroke, is it possible to make ng-table wait until I want to send my filter to the server via a submit button?

```
  $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: if page then page else 1,
    count: 10,
    sorting: { invoice_no: 'desc'}
  }, {
    total: 0,

    getData: ($defer, params) ->
      Invoice.query params.url(), (data) ->
        params.total($scope.total)

        # put params in url
        $location.search(params.url())

        # Paginate / update table with new data
        $defer.resolve(data)
  })
```

My current view

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table">
  <tr class='listing' ng-repeat="invoice in $data">
    <td data-title="'Invoice No.'" sortable="'invoice_no'" filter="{'invoice_no':'text'}">
      {{invoice.invoice_no}}
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

An inline filter will get called many times.

To call the filter once when the submit button is clicked, add a click handler:

```
<button type="submit" ng-click="onSubmit()" />
```

In your controller, invoke your filter inside your click handler:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $filter) {
   $scope.$data = [];

   $scope.onSubmit = function() {
       $scope.$data = $filter('filter')($scope.data, {'invoice_no':'text'});
   }
});
```

Comment: Do I have to do a '$scope.tableParams.reload()' after I change the filter? Shouldn't I be adding it to the params.url() instead?

Comment: Just found a better way of doing this would be to upgrade to ng-table 0.32 and use filterDelay